# Good jQuery popup dialog plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, popup

Do you know some good jQuery popup dialog plugins? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [FaceBox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) in a project I am working on right now. I like it. Does not require jQueryUI.

Comment: that is the minimum compatible version. fine for 1.4.2 or any version including and after 1.2.1

Comment: how to set the position of the popup box??

Comment: @zjm1126, this is JS, there are any number of ways to position. You can `$(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() {$('#facebox').css('top', '10px').css('left', '10px');});` . Take a look at the source to get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: @zjm1126 - on second thought, after looking at thinkswan's answer - colorbox seems to be a much better engineered script. I am going to investigate it, I suggest you do as well.

Answer (score 1):

I like the one built into jQuery UI built in dialog the best. Very customizable, theme integration, overload confirms and alerts.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog.

Comment: jQuery UI's pretty hefty if you just want modal dialogs, though.

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite is [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/). It's extremely easy to use and looks **great**! Check out their 5 different pages of examples for a quick how-to.

It also automatically detects the size of the content being loaded so you don't have to specify a width and height.

[alt text http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/4859/colorbox.png](http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/4859/colorbox.png)

Comment: It supports all the wonder of callbacks as well. It can be resized on the fly too.

The only thing it's missing, in my opinion, is the option to have it scroll with you as you scroll around the page.

Comment: that should not be too hard to do. You should either suggest it to the author or monkeypatch (or duckpunch) it yourself and send the patch to the author. Leave a comment for me if you do. Cheers and thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

[Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) looks awesome and is really versatile. Used it in a couple of projects and my clients are really happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my custom jquery dialog: https://jsfiddle.net/mm7b7t5t/
Still trying to add new features and improve it ^^

```
var example = new popup([{text: "Close}], "Title", "<p>Hello World</p>");
example.open();
```