# jquery: any non-jqueryui" dialog plugins with iframe/html support?

Tags: jquery, dialog, popup, draggable, resizable

i've been searching the net for the majority of the night with little success.

my friend and i are after a draggable dialog using jquery and not jquery UI because it feels rather bloated, especially with all that theme stuff it bundles with.

what i'm after in particular is one that supports

- iframe and/or HTML
- draggable
- optionally non-modal usage
- ability to display more than one at a time
- resizable

while posting this i've looked though the suggestions in stackoverflow

- [jQuery Modal Dialog without jQueryUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789773/jquery-modal-dialog-without-jqueryui)
- [What is the best alternative for jQuery thickbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050174/what-is-the-best-alternative-for-jquery-thickbox)
- [Good jQuery popup dialog plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481396/did-you-know-some-good-jquery-popup-dialog-plugins)

the best once i've found so far are:

- [ColorBox - customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)
- [FancyZoom meet jQuery](http://orderedlist.com/blog/articles/fancyzoom-meet-jquery/)
- [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)

and searched through [The Lightbox Clones Matrix](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/) (pretty damn cool site)

Comment: Your last link (lightbox comparison) is awesome. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! I ended up using jquery-ui without the bundled CSS.